# Adding diagonal pixel border in gimp

Tags: gimp, borders

I am looking to create a simple border in Gimp and have tried both the selection >> border and both the stroke selection methods and both are not creating what I am looking for. The stroke selection technique is the closest I have gotten. I am looking to create an outline in gimp around a selection using diagonals. Like the following (the dark purple):[image]

However I am getting it on the top but on the bottom, I am ending up with this:[image]

How would I go about making the border like the top (connected diagonally) all the way around. I could do it manually but I have spent hours doing this tedious task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One technique would be to use a path, and then stroke the path with the Paint tool option set to Pencil, and with the Pencil Tool itself set to 1px.

Example
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out the problem by changing the border width to 1.5 pixels. Well problem solved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/66269)

Comment: @CircleB: This is an attempt to answer and clearly not suited to be a comment.

Comment: @PlanetProgram: Can you provide some details? For example, which of the aforementioned tools did you use? Also, I fail to reproduce this using either tool, as my border always ends up much thicker.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, may requires some slight manual corrections on the result:

- Add a new layer
- `Edit>stroke path` with a with of 2 pixels
- `Layer>Mask>Add layer mask` and initialize by transferring the alpha channel if the layer.
- Use the Threshold tool with a very high threshold (>250)